# Failed to build iOS app Error output from Android Studio - Xcode build (Flutter / Dart)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-studio, dart

When launching flutter program in Android Studio for iOS simulator, iOS app errors come up:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           42.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

Flutter doctor -v runs well. Any ideas about why will this happen?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the Flutter project is successfully built for the iOS build:**

- Open the terminal at the root directory of the Flutter project
- Clear the project-built folder with the command:

  ```
  flutter clean
  ```

  This command will delete the "build" directory in your project, which will clear any previously built.
- Get the project dependencies by running the command:

  ```
  flutter pub get
  ```

  This command will fetch and update all the required packages mentioned in the **"pubspec.yaml"** file
- Navigate to the **"ios"** directory using the command:

  ```
  cd ios
  ```
- Ensure the CocoaPods dependencies are installed successfully with the command:

  ```
  pod install
  ```
- Try to run the app from the Android Studio.
  **or**
  Open the `.xcworkspace` file (not the `.xcodeproj` file) in Xcode:

  ```
  [PROJECT-DIRECTORY]/ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  ```

[image: File directory]